# Maximizing given a set of constraints. Optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to solve this problem. But I am having a hard time. Can anyone help?

```
Max a
s.t. a<= 2x
     a<= 2y
     a<= y + 2z
     x + y + z = 1
     x, y, z >= 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use an LP solver?

Comment: A more general method is to transform it into the standard form $$\max z=\sum_{j} c_jx_j \\ \text{s.t. } \sum_{j} a_{ij}x_j \le b_j \quad (i=1,\dots,m) \\ x_j \ge 0 \quad (j=1,\dots,n)$$ and use simplex method to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to begin by solving a simpler problem:

- The numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive and sum to 1.
- I note that the remaining equations look *almost* like $a \leq 2x$,  $a\leq 2y$, $a \leq 2z$. The last one is a little different, though.
- If these *were* the constraints, the maximum for $a$ occurs when $x=y=z = \frac{1}{3}$. The reason it occurs when they're all equal is that the constraint $x+y+z=1$ means that increasing any one of them decreases one of the others.

  So the maximum solution is $a = 2x = 2y = 2z = \frac{2}{3}$.
- To find the solution to your constraints, you can modify accordingly.
- Once again, it seems like an optimal value of $a$ will probably occur when all the upper bounds are equal, so $2x = 2y = 2z + y$.
- This suggests that $x=y$, and that $z = \frac{y}{2}$.
- Under the condition $x+y+z = 1$, this forces $x+x+x/2 = 1$, so $x = y = 2z = \frac{2}{5}$.
- The maximum value occurs when $a$  attains this upper bound, so when $a = \frac{4}{5}$.